# How to assign JSON Object to Hibernate Pojo + ext js 4 + Java + spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, extjs

I am using JPA, Spring, Ext js 4 mvc and mysql5.0 server

One problem i am facing is that i am not able to insert my data to database using Hibernate + JPA.
I am sending the data to server side using JSON and then this object interact with database and insert the json object to the database.

I am sending the json data as

```
"Id": null,
"Name": "New task",
"StartDate": "2010-02-13T05:30:00",
"EndDate": "2010-02-13T05:30:00",
"Duration": 0,
"DurationUnit": "d",
"PercentDone": 0,
"ManuallyScheduled": false,
"Priority": 1,
"parentId": 22,
"index": 2,
"depth": 2,
"checked": null
```

my Hibernate POJO is

```
private int id;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private int percentDone;
private String name;
private int priority;
private double duration;
private String durationUnit;
private int index;
private int depth;
private int parentId;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "TASK_Id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int Id) {
    this.id = Id;
}

/**
 * @return the startDate
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TASK_Start_Date")
public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
/**
 * @param startDate the startDate to set
 */
public void setStartDate(Date StartDate) {
    this.startDate = StartDate;
}

/**
 * @return the endDate
 */    
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TASK_End_Date")
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
/**
 * @param endDate the endDate to set
 */
public void setEndDate(Date EndDate) {
    this.endDate = EndDate;
}

/**
 * @return the percentDone
 */    
@Column(name = "TASK_Percent_Done")
public int getPercentDone() {
    return percentDone;
}
/**
 * @param percentDone the percentDone to set
 */
public void setPercentDone(int PercentDone) {
    this.percentDone = PercentDone;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_Name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String Name) {
    this.name = Name;
}

/**
 * @return the priority
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_Priority")
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
/**
 * @param priority the priority to set
 */
public void setPriority(int Priority) {
    this.priority = Priority;
}

/**
 * @return the duration
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_Duration")
public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
/**
 * @param duration the duration to set
 */
public void setDuration(double Duration) {
    this.duration = Duration;
}

/**
 * @return the durationUnit
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_DurationUnit")
public String getDurationUnit() {
    return durationUnit;
}
/**
 * @param durationUnit the durationUnit to set
 */
public void setDurationUnit(String DurationUnit) {
    this.durationUnit = DurationUnit;
}

/**
 * @return the index
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_Index")
public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}
/**
 * @param index the index to set
 */
public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

/**
 * @return the depth
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_Depth")
public int getDepth() {
    return depth;
}
/**
 * @param depth the depth to set
 */
public void setDepth(int depth) {
    this.depth = depth;
}

/**
 * @return the parentId
 */
@Column(name = "TASK_ParentId")
public int getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}
/**
 * @param parentId the parentId to set
 */
public void setParentId(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}
```

when i am passing the above JSON data nothing get inserted to my database.
my hibernate query fires like

```
`Hibernate: insert into TASK(TASK_Depth, TASK_Duration, TASK_DurationUnit, TASK_End_Date, TASK_Index, TASK_Name, TASK_ParentId, TASK_Percent_Done, TASK_Priority, TASK_Start_Date)
values( ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
```

nothing get inserted to my database. As my class id is autoincreemented the record gets created with empty name, startDate, endDate, parentId

So my question is that what the things i am doing wrong. Is there any problem with my hibernate Pojo mappings . If yes then any one having solution to this problem may reply to my thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to divide your issue into several areas.

1. Have you tried to create a  POJO manually (without conversion from JSON) and store it in your DB? 
   If it works, your mappings are OK, if not - the POJO is not relevant here, fix your JPA mappings.
2. Assuming it worked, the issue must be converting your JSON (after all, somewhere on server it converts json (string) to Java Object and creates your POJO), maybe it fails to convert dates, or your framework is not set up properly. One way or another this should be 
   easily revealed by your favorite debugger :)

I remember I've used a Direct Web Remoting ([DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)) project to send data from ExtJS to the Java based server (the data was sent in a JSON format) so I can't really elaborate on your conversion method.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks mark for the reply. I had done necessary changes but still getting below error `Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property Name:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property StartDate:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property EndDate:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task` Do you have any solution for this ??

Comment: Well, actually I think the solution is written in your warnings: the JSONObject fails to convert the JSON you're trying to send to POJO. I guess you should send something like  {your_class_name_that_match_your_pojo_class_name { here_comes_your_json_as_you_described_above} }

Comment: is there any example you had to do so ?? Do I need to add all the Json Object to the Object Of my hibernate Pojo and then pass it to my Class

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you with an example (I just don't have one) but   is it your code that constructs the POJO from JSON? Is it your code that prints these warnings? If not, how do you invoke it and what do you pass there? Please write a complete example with the code snippets, the information you've provided is insufficient. This way people will help you a way more efficient

Comment: My POJO'S are created not by JSON but by using hibernate hbmtoddl property set to true. And this error comes when i tried to insert Json data object to my POJO. my JSON data i had provided is same as above JSON OBJECT AND MY POJO IS ALSO DEFINED ABOVE. THIS ERROR COMES WHEN I PASSED ALL NECESSARY VALUE TO GET INSERTED TO MY DATABASE. You had any solution ??

Comment: yes, I understand, I should have better not used the word 'construct', my mistake. It looks like your JSONObject class fails to populate data into your POJO. The data is not populated even before it comes do DB, so hibernate is not an issue here...

Comment: so what's the problem ?? I am passing json object to be get persisted using **Task newTask = (Task) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Task.class);** and my jsonObject are the jsonData and Task.class is the Pojo. So where is the mistake that doesn't allowed the Object to be get persisted to DB. ??

Comment: Hi I am having problem I am receiving the date in format of **2012-01-30T00:00:00** so how can I assign it to my Date variable startDate in JAVA pojo class.