# Not able to insert data using Hibernate template to mysql server

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

stackoverflow forum member i need some help from you. I am not able to insert my JPA POJO Object to my DB.

my JPA POJO is

```
private Integer taskId;
private Integer taskDepth;
private Double taskDuration;
private String taskDurationUnit;
private Date taskEndDate;
private Integer taskIndex;
private String taskName;
private Integer taskParentId;
private Integer taskPercentDone;
private Integer taskPriority;
private Date taskStartDate;

public Task() {
}

public Task(Integer taskDepth, Double taskDuration,
        String taskDurationUnit, Date taskEndDate, Integer taskIndex,
        String taskName, Integer taskParentId, Integer taskPercentDone,
        Integer taskPriority, Date taskStartDate) {
    this.taskDepth = taskDepth;
    this.taskDuration = taskDuration;
    this.taskDurationUnit = taskDurationUnit;
    this.taskEndDate = taskEndDate;
    this.taskIndex = taskIndex;
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.taskParentId = taskParentId;
    this.taskPercentDone = taskPercentDone;
    this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
    this.taskStartDate = taskStartDate;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TASK_Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getTaskId() {
    return this.taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(Integer taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Depth")
public Integer getTaskDepth() {
    return this.taskDepth;
}

public void setTaskDepth(Integer taskDepth) {
    this.taskDepth = taskDepth;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Duration", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Double getTaskDuration() {
    return this.taskDuration;
}

public void setTaskDuration(Double taskDuration) {
    this.taskDuration = taskDuration;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_DurationUnit")
public String getTaskDurationUnit() {
    return this.taskDurationUnit;
}

public void setTaskDurationUnit(String taskDurationUnit) {
    this.taskDurationUnit = taskDurationUnit;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TASK_End_Date", length = 10)
public Date getTaskEndDate() {
    return this.taskEndDate;
}

public void setTaskEndDate(Date taskEndDate) {
    this.taskEndDate = taskEndDate;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Index")
public Integer getTaskIndex() {
    return this.taskIndex;
}

public void setTaskIndex(Integer taskIndex) {
    this.taskIndex = taskIndex;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Name")
public String getTaskName() {
    return this.taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_ParentId")
public Integer getTaskParentId() {
    return this.taskParentId;
}

public void setTaskParentId(Integer taskParentId) {
    this.taskParentId = taskParentId;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Percent_Done")
public Integer getTaskPercentDone() {
    return this.taskPercentDone;
}

public void setTaskPercentDone(Integer taskPercentDone) {
    this.taskPercentDone = taskPercentDone;
}

@Column(name = "TASK_Priority")
public Integer getTaskPriority() {
    return this.taskPriority;
}

public void setTaskPriority(Integer taskPriority) {
    this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TASK_Start_Date", length = 10)
public Date getTaskStartDate() {
    return this.taskStartDate;
}

public void setTaskStartDate(Date taskStartDate) {
    this.taskStartDate = taskStartDate;
}
```

`Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property Name:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property StartDate:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property EndDate:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property Duration:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property DurationUnit:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property PercentDone:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property Priority:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property parentId:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property index:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task
Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean
WARNING: Tried to assign property depth:java.lang.Integer to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task`

**I had generated my JPA POJO using Hibernate Reverse Engineering. Don't able to understand what's the problem with my JPA POJO Object.**

**my JSON object I am passing is** 
`{
    "Name": "Final New task",
    "StartDate": "2012-01-02T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2012-01-06T00:00:00",
    "Duration": 4,
    "DurationUnit": "d",
    "PercentDone": 5,
    "Priority": 1,
    "parentId": 3,
    "index": 1,
    "depth": 3
}`

**Still not able to map my json object to JPA POJO Object and always above error is thrown.
Is there the problem with JSONObject datatype and JPA POJO Object datatype.**

Anyone has the solution of this problem, please help me to solve it.

I am using Hibernate JPA to interact to my database.

Yogendra Singh
Sr. Programmer
Kintudesigns.com

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697921/how-to-assign-json-object-to-hibernate-pojo-ext-js-4-java-spring . Why add new issues for the same thing? Just revise your original post

Answer (score 0):

The POJO code is incomplete, it lacks class header and @Entity annotation. Probably it was badly pasted.

Comment: i had added the @Entity annotation at the top of the class , so that's not the big issue, but might be the problem with conversion of datatype of jsonobject to Hibernate JPA pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the name of the fields of the table are "TASK_Name", "TASK_Start_Date", "TASK_End_Date", etc? Aren't they just called "Name", "Start_Date", "End_Date"? If so, then the property name of the annotation @Column would be wrong.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but "TASK_Name", "TASK_Start_Date", "TASK_End_Date" are the Database Table columns which are created using JPA and my POJO class has "taskName", "taskEndDate", "taskStartDate". so what's the problem ??

Comment: I see, but then the JSON object you are passing has properties with names "Name", "StartDate", etc. Aren't the warnings saying that the setters can't be found?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the warning messages that are seen is not an issue when you are using this library

to parse JSON to Java Objects but they are not errors. Now, why the objects are not stored to

database is an issue with Hibernate. There is no issue with the Entity Class you are using.

Look at the configuration files. If there is hibernate issues then there must been some output logs on error for this matter.

Comment: actually when i am inserting the record using Task newTask = (Task) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Task.class); where Task is my Class and jsonObject is my JSONObject data i had defined above. I am gettting error **`Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean WARNING: Tried to assign property Name:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task Jan 2, 2012 2:09:15 PM net.sf.json.JSONObject toBean WARNING: Tried to assign property StartDate:java.lang.String to bean of class com.gantt.model.Task`** I know the problem is due to type casting but not able to find the solution.